# Can I omit part of the sentence 'age of'?

Tags: word-order

**Sentence:**

> She got married at **the age of** 30

**Question:**

Can I omit the part of the sentence "the age of"?

> She got married at 30

Comment: Have you googled that phrase? Can you find any other examples of "at nn" used for ages?

Comment: @James K yes, I've googled it. i haven't found any of such examples

Comment: @Max: You might do better searching Google ***Books***, to avoid being misled by the vast amount of poor quality English (not just from non-native speakers! :) on the Internet at large. Here's a link to about 812 written instances of [got married at 18.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22got+married+at+18%22) For comparison, there are 106 instances of ***...at age 18***, and 366 of ***...at the age of 18***. And for what it's worth, just ***two*** instances of the incredibly cumbersome ***at 18 years of age***.

Comment: First result for "married at 30" http://www.huffingtonpost.com/evelyn-lauer/5-reasons-why-i-waited-until-30-to-marry_b_4764342.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when a number, without other context, is associated with a person it is generally understood to be their **age**

> My son is almost 8.
>   *my son is almost 8 years old*
>
> He graduated when he was 18.
>   *he graduated when he was 18 years old*
>
> She got married at 30.
>   *she was 30 years old when she got married*
>
> He died at 26.
>   *he died at 26 years of age*

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is perfectly valid as is:

> She got married at 30 years of age